# Add birthday input in register form, display on web page and filter using this data in customer management on shopify

Tags: date, tags, shopify, customization, liquid

I want to customize register form by adding birthday input on Shopify web site **without any apps**.
Then display birthday data on my web page.
And then filter function with month of birthday can be realized on customer management panel.
Please help me about that.

*My trouble is follows:*

***Using tags***

I add following code in main-register.liquid

```
 <input 
     type="text"
     name="customer[tags]"
     id="datepicker"
  />
  <label for="datepicker">
     生年月日
  </label>
```

Of course it works. But doesn't filter in customer management panel.

***Using notes***

So I tried following code in it.

```
  <input 
     type="text"
     name="customer[notes][birthday]"
     id="datepicker"
  />
  <label for="datepicker">
     生年月日
  </label>
```

Then I can't display on web page, this data.

***Using metafields***

I created birthday metafield on customer field of setting panel.
Using it, I can display and filter, unfortunately input didn't work in register form.
I tried it.

```
  <input 
     type="text"
     name="customer[custom][birthday]"
     id="datepicker"
  />
  <label for="datepicker">
     生年月日
  </label>
```

"custom" is birthday metafield's namespace, and "birthday" is value.

Please help me.
**NOTICE:** Without using app just coding